# Construct a homeomorphism from anchor ring to torus

Tags: general-topology, periodic-functions

The anchor ring $A$ is by definition the set of points of the form

$(\cos θ(2 + \cos ϕ),\sin θ (2 + \cos ϕ),\sin ϕ) , θ, ϕ ∈ \mathbb R$ ,
in $\mathbb R^3$

Construct a homeomorphism from $A$ to the torus $T^2$.

Honestly not too sure where to start any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your definition of $T^2$?

Comment: We are also given that we can regard $T^2$ as a quotient space of [0, 2π]×[0, 2π], and there is a natural
map   f : [0, 2π] × [0, 2π] −→ A (anchor ring) given by the formula in the question. It remains to define a
”good” map   g : $T^2$ −→ A

Comment: The definition for T^2 we are given is that it is equivalent to S^1 X S^1

Comment: So you have your $\phi$ and your $\theta$, and you want to know what a "good map" (or inverse of a good map) from them to $S^2$?

Comment: Yeah a good map from $S^2$ to A

Comment: So parameterize $S^1\subset\mathbb R^2$ with an element $t$ of $[0,2\pi]$ where the endpoints are identified, by $t\to(\cos t, \sin t)$, and parameterize $S^2$ with a pair $(t,u)$ similarly.  Now define the map $S^2\to A$ by sending $(t,u)$ to $(\phi(t,u)=t,  \theta(t,u)=u)$.  If you set $(\phi,\theta)=(u,t0$ you get a different one, and there are $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ of variations on this theme.

Comment: In https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4048510 take $R= 2$ and $r= 1$.